# Regular Expression for password validation in asp.net mvc

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I need a regular expression for validating password in asp.net mvc as follows :

1. password must be minimum 8 characters and maximum infinity
2. password should be alphanumeric
3. password should not contain any special characters.

i have used `[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\w.][a-zA-Z]+[\w.]` but it does not fulfill the criteria

Comment: and what have you tried!

Comment: i have used - [a-zA-Z0-9]+[\w.][a-zA-Z]+[\w.] but it does not fulfill the criteria

Comment: Just a note, but you're making things much less secure if you choose to forbid special characters.  You don't need to display them anywhere and you should be storing only a hash of the password which will be alphanumeric, assuming you follow best practices like these: http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: There are some great resources out there for regexs e.g. http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=password gives you lots that you can either use or easily adapt to what you need

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm not gonna explain you anything because you are just asking us to do your work but since is really easy, I'll just give it to you.

`^[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$`

Comment: Thanks for your help, im new to regular expressions, so i had no option but to ask it.

Comment: -1. This is a site for explanations. Down-vote the question, vote to close it, or move on if you don't feel it warrants a proper answer.